# Sqlite 3: Error opening the databaseIncorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 4 supplied

Tags: python, sqlite

I've already tried adding in a comma after Name and the question mark in "VALUES" and was getting a syntax error for my parthenthesis.

```
@app.route("/Disease/new", methods = ["POST"])
def addDisease():
    newDisease = {}
    conn = None
    try:
        jsonPostData = request.get_json()
        Name = jsonPostData["Name"]

        conn = sqlite3.connect("./dbs/ContactTracer.db")
        conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        sql = """
            INSERT INTO Disease(Name) VALUES(?)
        """
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, (Name))
        conn.commit()
        sql = """
            SELECT Disease.ID, Disease.Name
            From Disease
            Where Disease.ID = ?
        """
        cursor.execute(sql,(cursor.lastrowid,))
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        newDisease["ID"] = row["ID"]
        newDisease["Name"] = row["Name"]
    except Error as e:
        print(f"Error opening the database{e}")
        abort(500)
    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()

    return newDisease
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `()` and check if `INSERT` succeeded

```
cursor.execute(sql, Name)
...
if cursor.lastrowid:
    cursor.execute(sql, cursor.lastrowid)
```

Comment: Add stack trace, db schema, etc. to help identify the problem